# Is the norm $p(x) = \max_{t \in [0,2]}|x(t)| + \left(\int_0^1|x(t)|^7\right)^{1/7}$ on $C[0,2]$ induced by any scalar product?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> I have a norm on space $X = C[0,2]$:
>   $$p(x) = \max_{t \in [0,2]}|x(t)| + \left(\int_0^1|x(t)|^7\right)^{1/7}$$
>   Is that norm induced by any scalar product?

I try to find counterexample for parallelogram identity 
$$||f+g||^2 + ||f-g||^2 = 2(||f||^2 + ||g||^2)$$ 
Why I tried to find it? Because I know the norm 
$$d(x) = \max_{t \in [0,2]}|x(t)|$$ 
can't be induced by any scalar product. Maybe I should use polar identity: $$(f,g) = \frac{1}{4}(||f+g||^2 + ||f-g||^2)$$

And then what to do with the norm, where instead of the integral - the sum? For example on space $C[-1,1]$:
$$k(x) = \max_{t \in [-1,1]}\pi^{2t}|x(t)| + 5\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left|x(-1+\frac{3}{2k})\right|^2}{k^5}\right)^{1/2}$$

Here, too, nothing happened. I know that a sum can be obtained from the scalar product (if $p=2$), if we consider it as a separate norm. And the maximum is impossible. How to work with such norms, where one of two norm can be induced?

Can you tell me a trick or something? Thank!

P.S (Edit): Maybe there is a chance to somehow prove that it is impossible to induce any norm that already includes a norm that is not inducible by anything?

Comment: Trying to find a counterexample for parallelogram identity is a good idea. And that is not working?

Comment: I considered such functions that the integral was well considered. I tried about five examples that came to mind, but none of them turned out to be a counterexample.

Comment: It seems to be a counter example, used for max separately: $f = cos(\frac{{\pi}t}{4})$, $g=sin(\frac{{\pi}t}{4})$ But the integrals there are heavy, counted them with the help of wolframalpha and it seems like it happened. Maybe there is a chance to somehow prove that it is impossible to induce any norm that already includes a norm that is not inducible by anything?

Comment: Surely some polynomials of low degree will be good counterexamples for the parallelogram law.

Comment: for example $f(t)=1$ and $g(t)=t$.

Comment: @GEdgar, yes, I tried it just and it worked out! Thank you! But now it is more interesting to try to prove a general statement about norms of this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\cos \pi x & 0 \le x \le 1/2\\
0 & 1/2 \le x \le 2
\end{cases}$$

and $g(x) = f(2-x)$. You have $f,g \in \mathcal C([0,2],\mathbb R)$. Let
$$I = \left(\int_0^2|f(t)|^7\right)^{\frac{1}{7}}=\left(\int_0^2|g(t)|^7\right)^{\frac{1}{7}} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\int_0^2|f(t)+g(t)|^7\right)^{\frac{1}{7}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_0^2|f(t)-g(t)|^7\right)^{\frac{1}{7}}$$ and notice
that 
$$1=\max_{t \in [0,2]}\vert f(t)\vert=\max_{t \in [0,2]}\vert g(t)\vert=\max_{t \in [0,2]}\vert f(t)+g(t)\vert=\max_{t \in [0,2]}\vert f(t)-g(t)\vert$$

Hence

$$\Vert f+g \Vert^2+\Vert f-g \Vert^2 =2(1+2I)^2 \neq 4(1+I)^2= \left(\Vert f \Vert^2 + \Vert g \Vert^2\right)^2$$

as $I < \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$.

Which allows to conclude.

**Using the parallelogram identity is a general way to decide if a norm is induced by an inner product according to [THE JORDAN-VON NEUMANN THEOREM](https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m113w10/public_html/jordan-vneumann-thm.pdf)**

Comment: Thanks for the elegant counterexample!